# how to set multilines textview in tablerow

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

I want to create multiple lines textview in tablerow and use the following codes but the long text of column covers whole width . How can I set **mutli-lines textview in tablerow**?

[image]

[image]

```
    TableLayout getClassBookTable(ArrayList<String> titles, String json) {
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        try {

            tableLayout.addView(getTitles(titles, false));
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
//            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
//                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
//            params.span = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                TextView snTextView = getTableTextView();
                snTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("s.n."));
//                snTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                tableRow.addView(snTextView);

                TextView bookTextView = getTableTextView();
                bookTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("book"));
//                bookTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                tableRow.addView(bookTextView);


                TextView subjectTextView = getTableTextView();
                subjectTextView.setSingleLine(false);
                subjectTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("subjectString"));
//                subjectTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                tableRow.addView(subjectTextView);


                TextView publisherTextView = getTableTextView();
                publisherTextView.setSingleLine(false);
                publisherTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("publisher"));
//                publisherTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                tableRow.addView(publisherTextView);


                TextView authorTextView = getTableTextView();
                authorTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("author"));
//                authorTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                tableRow.addView(authorTextView);

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);


            }
```

**EDITTED**
when I add the following codes
   tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
and its layout is shown below
[image]

Comment: what is your expected out put and what you get output from above code? you need to give more info about your problem

Comment: share your xml code

Comment: sorry no xml file 
only just codes

Comment: @nilesh I have added its screenshots

Answer (score 2):

Create a xml code like this:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:stretchColumns="0"
android:shrinkColumns="*">    //shrink your columns like this  android:shrinkColumns="0"as per your requirement and make sure text view will wrap text.

<TableRow>
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/question"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

java code:

```
TableLayout table_layout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.table);
table_layout.setColumnShrinkable(1,true);
```

please try this code, it helps you.

Comment: I have added the following codes 
 tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true); tableLayout.setColumnStretchable(0, true); 
and there is still problem and its screenshot is added above